# xhr.setRequestHeader is not working in Firefox but working in IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Here i am passing a http request header value through jquery ajax call..It is working only with IE and not working in Firefox.The  ajax call itself is not happening in firefox when  `xhr.setRequestHeader` is there in the code

```
var Call = function () {
$.support.cors = true;
var input = {
             RefId: "111", LoginId: "222", Id: "33", FirstName: "aaa", LastName: "bbb"
            };
var url = document.URL;
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("URL", url);
            },
            url: "http://localhost:40780/Service.svc/Insertion",
            data: JSON.stringify(Input),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the reason could be found here, by the way client and server handle CORS and preflight requests :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

> CORS from JQuery
>
> JQuery's $.ajax() method can be used to make both regular XHR and CORS
>   requests. A few notes about JQuery's implementation:
>
> JQuery's CORS implementation doesn't support IE's XDomainRequest object. But there are JQuery plugins that enable this. See
>   http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283 for details.
>       The $.support.cors boolean will be set to true if the browser supports CORS (This returns false in IE, see bullet above). This can
>   be a quick way to check for CORS support.

```
  headers: {
    // Set any custom headers here.
    // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
    // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
  },
```

Hope this will help